# Will a UNICODE string just containing ASCII characters always be equal to the ASCII string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, character-encoding, python-unicode

I noticed the following holds:

```
>>> u'abc' == 'abc'
True
>>> 'abc' == u'abc'
True
```

Will this always be true or could it possibly depend on the system locale?
(It seems strings are unicode in python 3: e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615662/python-3-if-a-string-contains-only-ascii-is-it-equal-to-the-string-as-bytes), but bytes in 2.x)

Comment: The characters in the ASCII set are codepage agnostic. It's only the extended characters (0x80 to 0xff) that can differ between locales.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: there are plenty of encodings that do *not* use ASCII as a base.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Python 2 coerces between `unicode` and `str` using the ASCII codec when comparing the two types. So yes, this is *always* true.

That is to say, unless you mess up your Python installation and use [`sys.setdefaultencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setdefaultencoding) to change that default. You cannot do that normally, because the `sys.setdefaultencoding()` function is *deleted* from the module at start-up time, but there is a Cargo Cult going around where people use `reload(sys)` to reinstate that function and change the default encoding to something else to try and fix implicit encoding and decoding problems. This is a dumb thing to do for precisely this reason.

Comment: What's exactly is wrong with `sys.setdefaultencoding()`?

Comment: @techtonik: changing the system default can break packages that rely on the default to be ASCII, and changing it only *masks* the issues your code has with relying on implicit encoding and decoding. If you were to set it to Latin-1 all byte-unicode decodings magically work but won't actually make sense, if you set it to UTF-8 all unicode-byte encodings will work but may not make sense, etc. You are effectively pre-spalking up your leg in case it breaks, rather than avoid breaking your leg in the first place.

Comment: Looks like a [workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/) problem to me. Is there a more real/explicit example?

Comment: @techtonik: I fail to see how this is a obscure side effect that some users want to maintain. That's frankly a ridiculous over-simplification of the issues. See [Dangers of sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29561747) for a concrete example.

Comment: @techtonik: if you are classifying this as a XKCD workflow issue then we may as well switch Python to be a fully weakly typed language such as JavaScript.

Comment: @techtonik I don’t get why you think that it’s a workflow issue when packages rely on the sane default value of something that cannot be changed in a non-hackish way. If anything, you trying to get around it just to change it so you get a “fixed behavior” (for your particular issues—or workflow) is the real workflow problem.

Comment: Well, it is not a workflow issue, but rather a FUD issue, because it is hard (if not impossible) to find the explanation and examples that illustrates the bad behaviour and aforementioned package conflict. The workflow slide, actually, contains a good detailed explanation of the issue that person has, and this one is very abstract. So, yes, I basically hoping for good answers to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29561747 to appear.

Comment: @anatolytechtonik see https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/